# SignalR : Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: javascript, asp.net, signalr

I When my client system done format, i got signalR Error like "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED"..

Hub not created. getting empty. localhost/8080/hubs not generated.

I tried few ways
1) disable windows firewall
2) Window 7 OS and Service pack 1 /Dot net framework 4.5 installed
3) Chrome Version used 66 updated version
4) Enable iis all features in windows turn on futures

Still i got same issue. hub not generated. [before format its working fine]

Any idea, pls share me.

Thanks and regards
Angappan.S